# Plex Media Server cannot seem to find data on my disks

Tags: mount, fstab, plex

I have a few drives with content on, and I've added these to a media library for TV Shows. I've mounted them under /media/username and added the mounts to my fstab so they're mounted upon boot. This is what I found to be essential in the documentation from Plex.

The problem is that Plex does not find any content there, even though I can browse the files from the Files-application (and they're mounted there when the system starts.)
The drives from `fstab`:

```
/dev/sdb1    /media/esso/Kilo   ntfs    defaults     0        2
/dev/sdc1    /media/esso/Golf   ntfs    defaults     0        2
/dev/sdd1    /media/esso/Delta   ntfs    defaults     0        2
/dev/sde1    /media/esso/Bravo   ntfs    defaults     0        2
/dev/sdf1    /media/esso/Hotel   ntfs    defaults     0        2
```

I suspect that some of the paramteres are wrong, but I can't figure them out. 
I've now added UUIDs as suggested.

Note that my library used to work with Plex on a Windows-installation, so I follow the naming conventions etc. Examples:
[image: eHow it looks in the terminal]
[image: How it looks in Plex]

All suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, I had this issue once. This helped me.

By default, Ubuntu now uses UUID to identify partitions.

**UUID=xxx.yyy.zzz**

To list your devices by UUID use blkid

```
sudo blkid
ls -l /dev/disk/by-uuid
```

Your end result might be something like this:

```
UUID=12102C02102CEB83 /media/esso/Bravo ntfs defaults 0 2
```

Make sure your folders have read/write permissions.

```
chmod -R a+x /media/esso
```

Comment: I tried this now, thanks! My drives are still mounted, but Plex still can't get my files. I assume that the folders are there as I can reach my files from any other application, but maybe there's some settings I've missed there?

Comment: "chmod -R a+x /media/esso" I think you need read/write.